# Java new Interface instance syntax - what's happening?

Tags: java, interface

What happens when you declare a new instance of an Interface as follows:

```
OnClickListener oc = new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
         //Something
    }
};
```

Where is the method `onClick` stored? Its got to be in some sort of class storage? Does this mean that this syntax creates an unnamed class and implicitly implements the OnClickListener interface to it? If so, how come you can assign different `OnClickListener` objects to each other? Surely as they are 'implicitly' different class types, this assignment of two different classes is impossible.

Could someone explain?

Comment: Congratulations, you've discovered anonymous classes. The assignment is possible because the classes implement the same interface, which serves as the type for the reference.

Comment: Good question. But I recommend you to read some book about basics of Java. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called an *Anonymous class*.

If your code is in File `Foo.java`, and you compile it, you would get `Foo.class` and `Foo$1.class` for the first anonymous class. (`Foo$2.class` and so on for more anonymous classes).

Answer (score 2):

```
OnClickListener oc = new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
         //Something
    }
};
```

is an **anonymous class** in java. you are creating an **anonymous class(which doesnt have a class name)** that **implements** your **OnClickListener**. so your method **OnClick()** which is   defined inside your interface **onClickListener** is being implmented here.

Answer (score 1):

Whats happening in here is that you are creating an "inner anonymous class" in java that implements the OnClickListener interface. This results in that the oc reference variable to refer to the object that results from the instantiation (thats where the implementation of the onClick method is).

This type of assignment is perfectly valid, the oc reference variable can be assigned another instance of an implementation of the OnClickListener as they both of the same type (implements the same interface) in that case the original "anonymous inner class" will become eligible for garbage collection as there are "zero" references to it.

Cheers;
Hass.